# PHP/MySQL - how to complete dropdown selection from list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm cobbling together a dropdown list that I would like to display the '[ve_venue]", "[ve_town]' from a MySQL query and, upon selection set a variable that I can use to pass the ve_ID on to an update query that adds a venue ID number to a separate table as a lookup key.

So far I've got some code that I've pieced together from various places and I can get it to display the town in a dropdown - I just need to add the venue field to the dropdown so I get "venue, town" in the list and I also need to be able to pass the ve_ID to a variable, say, $ve_ID so I can call it in some separate code (that will be on the same page in a separate include).

Here's what I've got so far....

```
<? 
include('login_admin_sucess.php');
// Connects to your Database 
include '../connect_include.php';

$query = "SELECT ve_ID, ve_venue, ve_town FROM         `co_venues` ORDER BY ve_ID ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$ve_venue = $r['ve_venue'];
$result_array[$ve_venue][] = $r['ve_town'];
}


echo "<select name='x'>";
foreach($result_array as $v_venue => $value)
{
foreach($value as $title) {
echo "<option value='" . $v_venue . "'>" . $title . "</option>";
}
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I realise that mysql_ is deprecated...I'll work on that once I've got everything functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat the id and venue.  For example:

$ve_venue = $r['ve_venue'] . "|" . $r['ve_ID'];

When you use the variable make a split with charapter "|" with preg_split function.

Comment: ...that makes sense! On that basis, I've updated my SQL query to concatenate 'ID Venue Town' so I now only need to pull out that one field - I'll update my code later to reflect this. Question: is the result of the dropdown selection already being stored as a variable? ...or do I still need to put that in?

Comment: It store in a variable with the name of de Combo ('x' in your code).  If method in the form is GET then $_GET['x'], else if POST then $_POST['x']